# ANT: replace param in set of XML files based on XML file content

Tags: xml, ant

I have directory with subdirs with xml files in it with different extensions.

---

**Start of updated part**

---

Target dir: `/some/path`

Target files mask: `*.load`

Basic filterset we use to find `*.load` files under `/some/path`:

```
<fileset dir="/some/path">
    <include name="**/*.load" />
</fileset>
```

There could by multiple subdirs under `/some/path` and multiple `*.load` files also.

But we need to enhance filtering based on XML content and params described in examples, use cases below.

Examples:

**load_file1.load:**

```
<load 
    id="0a0740d1fc1a33a28f1397b76cae48bc"
    order="9"
    enable="true"
    name="Load name 1"
    type="LoadType.custom">
    <parent />
    <default-property name="Property2"
                      type="java.lang.Integer"
                      value="0" />
    <default-property name="Property1"
                      type="java.lang.Boolean"
                      value="false" />
</load>
```

**load_file2.load:**

```
<load 
      id="ec9ca08d11ca34b42e13c5f21578d82c"
      name="Load name 2"
      order="0"
      enable="true"
      type="LoadType.base">
    <parent />
    <default-property name="Load name 1"
                      type="java.lang.String"
                      value="test3" />
    <default-property name="Property2"
                      type="java.lang.Integer"
                      value="0" />
    <!-- here could be any number of other sub-properties  -->
    <date-range end-date="1/31/1900"
                     start-date="1/31/1900" />
</load>
```

Input data:

Ant param: `Load_name = "Load name 1"` - used to find corresponding files

Ant param: `Load_param_name_replace = "enable"`

Ant param: `Load_param_value_replace = "false"`

**NB! We always search for files based on value of `//load/@name` attribute (hardcoded) inside them:**

```
<load 
      id="ec9ca08d11ca34b42e13c5f21578d82c"
      name="Load name 2"
      order="0"
      enable="true"
      type="LoadType.base">
```

Problem (based on example of files above):

1. We should find **files** where `//load/@name = $Load_name` ANT param ("*Load name 1*")
2. We should change in found files (could be multiple) XML attribute declared in `$Load_param_name_replace` ANT param ("*enable*") value to value of ANT param `$Load_param_value_replace` ("*false*")

**Expected results**:

1. File(s) is found: **load_file1.load**

**NB!** please pay attention that in **load_file2.load** we have `<default-property name="Load name 1" ...` that match combination `name="Load name 1"`, but we need to distinguish between this invalid case and valid one in file **load_file1.load**.

1. In found file(s) **load_file1.load** XML attribute defined in `$Load_param_name_replace` ("*enable*") ANT param under `//load` node should be changed to new value defined in ANT param `$Load_param_value_replace` ("*false*")

So after ANT task the file **load_file1.load** should look as:

```
<load 
    id="0a0740d1fc1a33a28f1397b76cae48bc"
    order="9"
    enable="false"
    name="Load name 1"
    type="LoadType.custom">
    <parent />
    <default-property name="Property2"
                      type="java.lang.Integer"
                      value="0" />
    <default-property name="Property1"
                      type="java.lang.Boolean"
                      value="false" />
</load>
```

---

**End of updated part**

---

As you can see xml files content is spread through multiple lines - that is the tricky part for me.

We tried ANT `fileset` target with `containsregexp` filters where searched for **multiline regex with `name="load_name1"`** but without success. We used `multiline=true` and `singleline=true` - didnt work either.

After that we tried **XMLtask** - but there were not enough examples of how to replace xml property in multiple .XML files based on some `fileset`.

So if you could provide a couple of examples - it'd be greatful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completely revised after updated problem description :**

```
<project>
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

<property name="editno" value='&lt;default-property name="Load name 1"'/>
<property name="edityes" value='name="Load name 1"'/>
<property name="editxpath" value="//load/@enable"/>
<property name="editnew" value="false"/>

 <xmltask todir="/some/path" report="true">
  <fileset dir="/some/path">
   <include name="**/*.load"/>
    <not>
     <contains text="${editno}" casesensitive="true"/>
    </not>
    <contains text="${edityes}" casesensitive="true"/>
   </fileset>
   <replace path="${editxpath}" withText="${editnew}"/>
  </xmltask>
</project>
```

for a quick check of the contents of a fileset simply use the builtin property ${toString:filesetid}

```
 <fileset dir="/some/path" id="foobar">
  <include name="**/*.load" />
  <not>
   <contains text="${editno}" casesensitive="true" />
  </not>
  <contains text="${edityes}" casesensitive="true" />
 </fileset>

 <echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>
```

see Ant manual [Properties and PropertyHelpers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#toString)

Comment: thx for example provided. One more point - we can't just validate that string "name='value'" exists in XML file because its structure could be more tricky and we could have some other node, not just root one <load> with key-value like "name='value'". So we want to be sure, that we check that param exactly for root node.

Comment: I updated example in a question. That is why we tried regex inside <fileset> first.

Comment: your updated more tricky example is a bit confusing : [1.]\\load\@name is no valid xpath expression, the valid expression //load/@name would yield load_name2 [2.] you search for name="whatever" only as attribute from load tag but not as attribute from property tag, right ?

Comment: Or does your updated more tricky example mean combine those two xml snippets ending up with a xmlsnippet containing two load tags, where the second one has a nested section with multiple property tags ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I updated xpath and provide a comment. Tricky it is about that properties could be nested to <load> node.

Comment: your updated example is looking for //load/property/@name param, but I need to distinguish between //load/property/@name and //load/@name and the latter should be equal to some specified value. That is why I was concerned about nested regexp to distinguish between two.

Comment: so something new after each update, you should give the whole details right from the beginning ;-) So some simple questions now, hope for some simple answers from you : [1] How does the xml files you're dealing with look like, a combination of xml_file1.load + xml_file2.load or xml_file2.load only ? [2] What's the condition for those xml files to get a target for the replacement ? [3] What should be replaced with what ? Maybe you should edit and cleanup your question as it get's more confusing with every edit IMO

Comment: I refactored a question providing thorough problem statement with file examples close to production and expected results. Hope it is clear enough! :) Thx for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Ant `XSLT` task to apply a transform like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="load[@name='load_name1']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="from">date2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='from']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This makes a copy of your input, replacing the `from` attribute on the tags matching `name="load_name1"`.  Note that this may change the indentation, but will work no matter how the input is formatted, which may not be possible with regular expressions.

Comment: Thx for example. We give this a try also!

Comment: @zmische - To use this stylesheet with your more tricky example, you will have to change the "apply-templates" to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='from']|node()"/>` (added `|node()` to select). You would also have to change "load_name1" in the predicate to "load_name2".